# How to get firestore data as stream?

Tags: flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore

I am making a collection group query, where upon matching a particular field, I am going a level backwards and then read the data.

I am able to do that in `Future` approach.

Here is my code returning future:

```
@override
  Future<Either<JobPostFailure, List<JobPost>>> readAppliedJobPosts({
    required String seamanId,
  }) async {
    final querySnapshot = await FirebaseFirestore.instance
        .collectionGroup(ConstStrings.applications)
        .where(
          ConstStrings.seamanId,
          isEqualTo: seamanId,
        )
        .get();

    final List<JobPost> mList = [];

    for (var docSnap in querySnapshot.docs) {
      final jobPostDocSnap = await docSnap.reference.parent.parent?.get();
      mList.add(JobPostDto.fromFirestore(jobPostDocSnap!).toDomain());
    }

    return right(mList);
  }
```

Now I am struggling to do this in `Stream` approach, where my return type would be something like this : `Stream<Either<JobPostFailure, List<JobPost>>>`. What is the equivalent of my above code in `Stream`?

My try so far :

```
@override
  Stream<Either<JobPostFailure, List<JobPost>>> watchAppliedJobPosts({
    required String seamanId,
  }) async* {
    yield* _firestore
        .collectionGroup(ConstStrings.applications)
        .where(
          ConstStrings.seamanId,
          isEqualTo: seamanId,
        )
        .snapshots()
        .map((event) {
      return event.docs.map((e) {
        return e.reference.parent.parent!.snapshots().map((event) {
          return right(JobPostDto.fromFirestore(event).toDomain());
        }).toList();
      });
    });
  }
```

And its a big mess!

Comment: Have you tried implementing `StreamBuilder` for this? Can you please provide any error you get when you execute the code?  The error would be useful for troubleshooting.

Answer (score 0):

You can use method `snapshots` instead of `get`. Is will create a new stream that will fetch data for every change your document or collection has

Comment: Already tried. Upon failure, seeking answer here.